# How to force a graph within a grid in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I have a grid that looks like this

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.set_xticks(numpy.arange(-5,6,1))
ax.set_yticks(numpy.arange(-5,6,1))
plt.grid(True)
```

When plotting an exponential function, obviously the function's values grow larger than the grid very quickly, and my grid ticks get distorted. I want the grid to be fixed, and only that part of the function to be graphed which fits inside of the grid. Is this possible?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the limits of the axes:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()

# Exponential plot:
x = linspace(-5, 5, 100)
y = power(2, x)
ax.plot(x, y)

ax.set_xticks(numpy.arange(-5,6,1))
ax.set_yticks(numpy.arange(-5,6,1))
ax.set_xlim(-5, 6)
ax.set_ylim(-5, 6)
plt.grid(True)
```

Comment: perfect!
Thank you!